# Python Web Scraping | How to scrape data from multiple urls by choosing page number as a range with Beautiful Soup and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C://Downloads//webdrivers//geckodriver.exe')
a = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Mobile&i=amazon-devices&page='
for c in range(8):

    #a = f'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Mobile&i=amazon-devices&page={c}'

    cd = driver.get(a+str(c))

    page_source = driver.page_source
    bs = Soup(page_source, 'html.parser')

    fetch_data = bs.find_all('div', {'class': 's-expand-height.s-include-content-margin.s-latency-cf-section.s-border-bottom'})

    for f_data in fetch_data:
        product_name = f_data.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-medium.a-color-base.a-text-normal'})
        print(product_name + '\n')
```

Now The problem here is that, Webdriver successfully visits 7 pages, But doesn't provide any output or an error.

Now I don't know where M in going wrong.

Any suggestions, reference to a article that provides solution about this problem will be always welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting the right div tag to fetch the products using BeautifulSoup, leading to no output.

Try the following snippet:-

```
#range of pages
for i in range(1,20):

    driver.get(f'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Mobile&i=amazon-devices&page={i}')
    page_source = driver.page_source
    bs = Soup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    
    #get search results
    products=bs.find_all('div',{'data-component-type':"s-search-result"})

    #for each product in search result print product name
    for i in range(0,len(products)):
        for product_name in products[i].find('span',class_="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"):
            print(product_name)
```

Comment: Hey That code worked, Can you suggest me how should i get the div of the class? All I've learnt is that if you select a box and when a green border appears at the end you find the div.

Comment: `products=bs.find_all('div',{'data-component-type':"s-search-result"})` this is part which fetches the div of each products on the page, the method which you are following to get div tags is right, but be careful when there are nested divs

Comment: What should I do for nested divs then? Can you suggest me an example of nested div? So my concept gets even more clear

Comment: [This](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/240985) link might be useful

Comment: Thank you for you help, Just wanted a last suggestion, as you know that search page and product page are different. Is there a way where i can find data of product page such as in stock etc. I dont want solution, I just want some steps to move forward .

Comment: If you carefully inspect the search page, you can get the link of each product, which on clicking redirects you to product page, and then you can get the product details from there. This can be done easily using selenium, you can find many resources about clicking elements and redirecting to new page using selenium online.

Answer (score 0):

You can print bs or fetch_data to debug.

Anyway

In my opinion, you can use `requests` or `urllib` to get page_source instead of selenium

Comment: Would you be able to provide any example?

Comment: @Mathues Torquato even I want that example